# How can use external python packages in an Ansible module?

Tags: ansible

I'm writing an Ansible Module in Python which will run on the target nodes(remote).

I know I'll be needing some python packages installed, but I don't understand how am I supposed to install those packages.

Is it just installing the packages on the target node? And if so , how can avoid conflicts between packages? I mean, I guess two modules may require different versions of the same package.

Or am I supposed to call from my module `python -m venv myenvname` and then get my module to execute `menvname/bin/python mycode.py` instead?

What is actual approach when you have a module that require packages from pypy?

Comment: The package will be either needed on the controller or on the target depending on what you are currently developing in your module. In either case, the module will have to be installed on the relevant system. If on the controller, you need to pip install in whatever environment Ansible is currently running in (check `ansible --version`). If on the target, this will depend on how you discover or not the python environment. For auto discovery, you need to install in whatever environment this will lead to. Else you can use `ansible_python_interpreter` to target an env.

Comment: For auto discovery and python interpreter on the target, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a python dependency management tool such as `poetry`

Ansible is also a python package, so you can use `poetry` to install `ansible` and any dependencies required for your custom modules

If you wanted to use `pandas` for your `ansible` module:

`pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "my-ansible"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
ansible = "8.2.0"
pandas = "2.1.0"
python = "3.10.*"
```

Then test with:

```
poetry shell
[...]
python
>>> import pandas
```

Comment: I perceive that as a workaround, especially problematic because the module user had to employ it. That puts a huge burden on the user, requires documentation in the module and it's also one more complexity and source for random failures that are hard to understand. Ansible should take care of target isolation, imho.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same question and my conclusion is not to use dependencies and if that's not an option not to write the module.

One of the biggest advantages of Ansible is in my opinion that it is agent-less, it does not require the target to be provisioned for Ansible. That's true as long as you don't consider the requirement of a python interpreter on the target to be an "agent", which I find reasonable.

But once you need to manage dependencies, e.g. having to manually deploy dependencies that may or may not influence the target system, then this is even worse than having to install an agent, because the price you pay is the same or higher. Higher because target deployment requirements are hidden or at least not really transparent.

I assumed that Ansible takes care to package the dependencies of a module when it's deployed on the target on run using some kind of virtual environment shielding this from the platform, but it doesn't.

I don't mind having to manage dependencies on the controller, but on targets this is a no-go for me.

It get's even worse, because Ansible favors plugins running on target over those running on the controller. F.e. you cannot create an info-action, it has to be an info-plugin, running on the target. So if you need dependencies or just don't want to copy and paste from python libraries, you hit the wall. This is especially annoying if you want to implement functionality interfacing with external services such as web-API's that do not depend on whether you do that from the controller or target.

I love using Ansible, it's a great tool and really convenient, but extending it is a nightmare and the little I know about its internal workings looks really messy.

Comment: You can of course use a venv yourself, but then it's your responsibility as a user of a module to ensure that the module's dependencies don't mess with the target. It should be the responsibility of Ansible or at least the module developer to shield that complexity from the user - just to clarify why I don't think the previous answer is really a solution.